# Is it possible in Asana to create rules that automatically shift tasks into a section?

Tags: rules, project-management

The title says it all. I work in an Asana project which gets flooded with tasks which are automatically created. It would help if I could automatically shift some tasks into a section based on their title, similar to an email application (Outlook, Gmail etc.) in which you can create rules which automatically move emails based on their title or other fields - is this possible in Asana?